# Get the names of variables from a web-page?

Tags: javascript, flash, variables

Is there a way to get the names of variables from a flash game? I have been playing with  my players health with the code;

```
javascript:document.embeds[0].SetVariable("_root.player.intHP", 0)
```

I am looking for a way to find out the rest of the variables, like damage and such.
Thanks in advance

Comment: A better name for this would be something like "Get variables from an embedded flash object with javascript".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ExternalInterface API in Flash. It will map a function inside of Flash to a be accessible through the interface.

AS3 - map an internal function to a js function

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
if (ExternalInterface.available) 
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("getMyVar", sendMyVar);

function(){
  return myFlashVar;
}
```

JS - call the function name on the external interface

```
var jsMyVar = myFlashMovie.getMyVar();
```

You can also pass params to set information as well but need to add it in the Flash Movie.

If you dont have access to the Flash code you can't bridge between JS and As3.

Comment: Its an online game, so I don't have access to its scripts. Thanks for the thought though